Getting an error hooking up enable3d to a threejs project
I'm trying to setup a project that will be using both threejs and enable3d. I'm NOT using nodejs. I just want to set it up as a standalone website that includes all of the js files and so on. I've downloaded js files for threejs and enable3d. I followed the docs for both. I have no issues getting threejs to work, but I can't seem to successfully add enable3d physics to it.
Here is my setup. This is a the first 3 lines of main.js module and complete index.html:


import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import * as ENABLE3D from 'enable3d';
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
        
        <script type="importmap">
            {
              "imports": {
                "three": "./js/three.module.min.js",
                "three/addons/": "./js/jsm/",
                "enable3d": "./js/enable3d.ammoPhysics.0.25.4.min.js"
              }
            }
        </script>
        <script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>



When I run this I get
Uncaught TypeError: r is undefined       enable3d.ammoPhysics.0.25.4.min.js:1:11952
<anonymous> http://localhost:5000/js/enable3d.ammoPhysics.0.25.4.min.js:1
<anonymous> http://localhost:5000/js/enable3d.ammoPhysics.0.25.4.min.js:1
<anonymous> http://localhost:5000/js/enable3d.ammoPhysics.0.25.4.min.js:1
<anonymous> http://localhost:5000/js/enable3d.ammoPhysics.0.25.4.min.js:1
<anonymous> http://localhost:5000/js/enable3d.ammoPhysics.0.25.4.min.js:1

This is caused by the 3rd line in main.js: "import * as ENABLE3D from 'enable3d';"
I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I can't figure it out. I've tried all kind of permutations of this and can't get enable3d to initialize/run.
Any pointers or ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
